# how to flip content around for arabic content

Tags: layout, flip

I need to have a site that has both english and arabic options to it. Is there a simple way for me to flip the arabic content around so that it is viewed from right to left instead of left to right?

Here is my css

```
    .navigation-wrapper_arabic{
    font-family: 'GillSansLightRegular';
    font-size:15px;
    direction:rtl;
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}

.navigation-wrapper_arabic:hover{
    background:#000;    
}

.nav-arrow_arabic{
    float:right !important; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    padding:10px 0;
}

.nav-arrow_arabic img{
    display:block;  
}

.nav-arrow_arabic.active img{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;  
}

.nav-arrow_arabic.inactive img{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;  
}

.main-level-nav_arabic{
    /*padding:10px 0;*/
    position:relative;
    direction:rtl;
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}

.main-level-nav_arabic li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    direction:rtl;
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}

.main-level-nav_arabic a{
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:0 25px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    display:block;
    direction:rtl;
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560966/text-right-to-left-css

Comment: CSS has a left-to-right and right-to-left text property. You could use that on the body tag.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm being silly or not, but it's not working. I've added a direction:rtl and unicode-bidi: bidi-override to my classes. I've updated my question to have my css