# CSS- Right to Left Text Content

Tags: html, css, right-to-left, language-translation

So I've marked up a responsive page that the client not wants to be in Arabic. When provided with the copy changes I merely copied and pasted the translated text content into the mark up and added 'dir="rtl"' to my html line.

I've now received feedback from the client stating that the text is it is still reading incorrectly. I've removed the tag thinking that perhaps that was the error but I then got the same response. I have absolutely no idea what's wrong with the mark up.

```
<html class="no-js" dir="rtl">
<h3>عروض الكهرباء أصبحت أكثر تنافسية 
</h3>

                <p>
                    لقد تغيرت الكهرباء في نيو ساوث ويلز. فرفع القيود الرقابية عن الكهرباء يعني خطط أكثر تنافسية للكهرباء، والمزيد من الخيارات، وانخفاض أسعار الكهرباء في نيو ساوث ويلز؛ الأمر الذي يعود بالنفع على المنازل والشركات الصغيرة.
                </p>
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code posted. The HTML `dir` attribute (rather than the CSS `direction` property) is the recommended way of setting directionality, and it works well. So there must be something else that prevents it from working, like some misguided CSS Reset code. Besides, even with directionality set to left-to-right, the example in the question is rendered correctly as regards to text direction, except for the final period, which is misplaced on the right. (Text is aligned to the left, but this is a side effect rather than wrong text direction.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text: right to left (CSS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560966/text-right-to-left-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS property:

```
html {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Or inline CSS like this:

```
<html class="no-js" style="direction:rtl">
<h3>عروض الكهرباء أصبحت أكثر تنافسية 
</h3>

                <p>
                    لقد تغيرت الكهرباء في نيو ساوث ويلز. فرفع القيود الرقابية عن الكهرباء يعني خطط أكثر تنافسية للكهرباء، والمزيد من الخيارات، وانخفاض أسعار الكهرباء في نيو ساوث ويلز؛ الأمر الذي يعود بالنفع على المنازل والشركات الصغيرة.
                </p>
```

Comment: Hey, That worked! Though I have text in a lightbox carousel that is now gone.

Comment: Any ideas on why the text is disappeared in the light box?

Comment: @BBMAN, this just overrides some setting you have elsewhere. There is no guarantee that this happens to fix all issues caused (probably) by some global CSS code not disclosed in your question.

Answer (score 1):

simple apply `text-align: right;` to `p` tag OR you can apply `direction: rtl;` also.