# How to simulate <bdi> on IE11?

Tags: javascript, html, polyfills

I'm developing a web app which supports multiple browsers & languages including Arab so it has to support `right-to-left` direction. However, the HTML5 `<bdi>` ([document here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_bdi.asp)) tag doesn't work on IE11, do you know any way to handle this compatibility issue?

Comment: Don't bother with IE11. It will soon disappear and be overtaken by Edge. Also only roughly 4% of WWW-users use IE/Edge browser.

Comment: There're 2 reasons I have to find out a way to fix this issue: it's project's requirements & Edge doesn't support `<bdi>` also

Comment: You should go for Edge and stop working on IE11. IE11 have several more codes that doesn't work.

Comment: I have no other choice, it's a huge project & I'm only a frontend developer. As I said above, Edge still not support `<bdi>`

Comment: @SimonJensen "Don't bother with IE11. It will soon disappear and be overtaken by Edge" What's your definition of "soon"?

Comment: `<bdi/>` is only supported in Firefox and Chrome [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdi#Specifications).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS- Right to Left Text Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030934/css-right-to-left-text-content)

Comment: @Paul i thought that also but op didn't tag css.

Comment: @A.Meshu Fair point, but I try to think of these things in terms of the goal of the question, not necessarily what they actually asked or tagged.  A lot of folks (especially inexperienced people) don't know what to actually ask.

Comment: Agree @Paul. Nevertheless my answer works with Hebrew so i guess Arabic will act the same (-:

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i completely understand what you try to achieve, have you tried something like

```
<p lang="ar" dir="rtl">
```

This should work if you want to put Arab text.